# EndLessAdapter and Custom Fragmentlist

Tags: android, fragment, cwac-endless

I'm trying to use this example ( http://droidista.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/using-cwacs-endlessadapter-with-custom.html?showComment=1369770178127#c166648792344448629 ) with in a fragment and I'm running in to problems

```
class DataAdapter extends EndlessAdapter {
private RotateAnimation rotate=null;
ArrayList tempList = new ArrayList();

CustomAdapter() {
super(new CustomArrayAdapter(EndlessCustom.this, 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, eventsSub));

// problem at CustomArrayAdapter

rotate=new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
0.5f);
rotate.setDuration(600);
rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
}
```

> "The constructor EndlessCustom.CustomArrayAdapter(EndlessCustom, int,
>   int, ArrayList) is undefined"

I suspect its a context issue which I am trying to work though but if you could give me any suggestions on how to work this issue out I would appreciate it. Thanks

EDIT - The Whole class....

```
// http://droidista.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/using-cwacs-endlessadapter-with-custom.html

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.commonsware.cwac.endless.EndlessAdapter;

public class EndlessCustom extends Fragment {

 static int LIST_SIZE;
 private int mLastOffset = 0;

 static final int BATCH_SIZE = 10;

 ArrayList<String> eventsSub = new ArrayList<String>();

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dod_events, container, false);
  //Do Stuff Here
     init();
     return root;
 }

 private void init() {
  LIST_SIZE = EVENTS.length;  
  for (int i=0; i<=BATCH_SIZE; i++){
   eventsSub.add(EVENTS[i]);   
  }
  setLastOffset(BATCH_SIZE);
  displayList(eventsSub);
 }

 private void setLastOffset(int i) {
  mLastOffset = i;  
 }

 private int getLastOffset(){
  return mLastOffset;
 }

 private void displayList(ArrayList<String> eventsSub) {  
  setListAdapter(new DataAdapter());
 }

 private class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

  public CustomArrayAdapter(Context endlessCustom, int resource,
    int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
   super(endlessCustom, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
  }  

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ViewHolder holder;    

   if(convertView==null){
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321343/android-getsystemservice-inside-custom-arrayadapter   
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //EndlessCustom.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.word = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

    convertView.setTag(holder);
   } else{
    holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
   }

   holder.word.setText(String.valueOf(position+1) + ". " + eventsSub.get(position));
   return convertView;
  }

  public class ViewHolder{
   public TextView word;        
  }  
 }





 class DataAdapter extends EndlessAdapter {
  private RotateAnimation rotate=null;
  ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();

  DataAdapter() {
   super(new CustomArrayAdapter(EndlessCustom.this, 
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, eventsSub));

   // problem at CustomArrayAdapter

   rotate=new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
     0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
     0.5f);
   rotate.setDuration(600);
   rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
   rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
  }






  @Override
  protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {

   View row=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);

   View child=row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
   child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   child=row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
   child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   child.startAnimation(rotate);

   return(row);
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean cacheInBackground() {
      // update here to get data method rather than string
      // ParseJSONurl
   tempList.clear();
   int lastOffset = getLastOffset();
   if(lastOffset < LIST_SIZE){
    int limit = lastOffset + BATCH_SIZE;
    for(int i=(lastOffset+1); (i<=limit && i<LIST_SIZE); i++){
     tempList.add(EVENTS[i]);
    }    
    setLastOffset(limit);

    if(limit<LIST_SIZE){
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
   } else  {
    return false;
   }
  }


  @Override
  protected void appendCachedData() {

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapterNew = (ArrayAdapter<String>)getWrappedAdapter();

   int listLen = tempList.size();
   for(int i=0; i<listLen; i++){
    arrAdapterNew.add(tempList.get(i));
   }
  }
 }


 static final String[] EVENTS = new String[] {
        "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", 
        "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina",
        "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
        "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium",
        "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
        "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Bouvet Island", "Brazil", "British Indian Ocean Territory",
        "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi",
        "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde",
        "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China",
        "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo",
        "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic",
        "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic",
        "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea",
        "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Faeroe Islands", "Falkland Islands", "Fiji", "Finland",
        "Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia", "France", "French Guiana", "French Polynesia",
        "French Southern Territories", "Gabon", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar",
        "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guadeloupe", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau",
        "Guyana", "Haiti", "Heard Island and McDonald Islands", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary",
        "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica",
        "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos",
        "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg",
        "Macau", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands",
        "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova",
        "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia",
        "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand",
        "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norfolk Island", "North Korea", "Northern Marianas",
        "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru",
        "Philippines", "Pitcairn Islands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar",
        "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Sqo Tome and Principe", "Saint Helena",
        "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
        "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal",
        "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands",
        "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands", "South Korea",
        "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Svalbard and Jan Mayen", "Swaziland", "Sweden",
        "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "The Bahamas",
        "The Gambia", "Togo", "Tokelau", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey",
        "Turkmenistan", "Turks and Caicos Islands", "Tuvalu", "Virgin Islands", "Uganda",
        "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom",
        "United States", "United States Minor Outlying Islands", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan",
        "Vanuatu", "Vatican City", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Wallis and Futuna", "Western Sahara",
        "Yemen", "Yugoslavia", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"
    };
}
```

Comment: plz show CustomArrayAdapter class code also

Comment: Added to the first post - thanks

Comment: ok have you tried this `super(new CustomArrayAdapter(EndlessCustom.this.getActivity(), 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, eventsSub));` ?

Comment: Brill - that worked. Could you explain why as I'm keen to learn rather than ask lots of questions all the time. Was I right about context ?

Comment: currently you are trying to pass Fragment Context instead of Activity Context which is associated with EndlessCustom Fragment . plz see my answer if this help u

Comment: Thank you ρяσѕρєя - I have marked it correct as it did indeed work.

Comment: Terran Glad I could help you in solving current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Fragment.getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)  for getting Activity Context which is associated with current Fragment. do it as:

```
CustomAdapter() {
        super(new CustomArrayAdapter(EndlessCustom.this.getActivity(), 
                                     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                                     android.R.id.text1, 
                                     eventsSub));
```

Comment: can you check here?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122304/endless-scrolling-listview-not-working