# Customizing android ListView items

Tags: android, listview

I have a question about customizing android ListView items:

I was following this tutorial: http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/customizing-android-listview-item-layout/

The first part, with normal R.android.simple_text_item_1 worked fine for me, so I get my ListView with Strings in every row.

Then I moved on and tried to modify the items of my ListView like described:

1. I defined this XML data for my list items. Its a LinearLayout that holds only two TextViews

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/username"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/email"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. I defined a data class UserRecord, that simply gives me the abiltity to create objects which consist of a name and an email adress

   ```
   public class UserRecord {
       public String username;
       public String email;

       public UserRecord(String username, String email) {
       this.username = username;
       this.email = email;
       }
   }
   ```
3. I copied the whole adapterclass, but I got one error, the line where I commented

   ```
   public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserRecord> {
   private ArrayList<UserRecord> users;

   public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<UserRecord>     users) {
   super(context, textViewResourceId, users);
   this.users = users;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View v = convertView;
       if (v == null) {
       //In the following line I get the error: "The method getSystemService is undefined
       //for type UserItemAdapter
       LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
       }

       UserRecord user = users.get(position);
       if (user != null) {
           TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);
           TextView email = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.email);

       if (username != null) {
           username.setText(user.username);
       }

       if(email != null) {
           email.setText("Email: " + user.email );
       }
   }
   return v;
   }
   }
   ```
4. I changed my onCreate method in the MainActivity like follows, maybe here's the fault.

   ```
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ArrayList<UserRecord> users = new ArrayList<UserRecord>();
   UserRecord a = new UserRecord("a","b");
   users.add(a);

   ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

   //The following adapter worked fine when using a String array
   //listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));

   //This adapter doesn't work I guess :(
   listView.setAdapter(new UserItemAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, users));

   }
   ```

Can anyone tell me, where my fault is? If I try to launch my app, it doesn't even start and my emulator says "unfortunately closed blabla". -.-

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use getSystemService in a non-activity class (LocationManager)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870667/how-can-i-use-getsystemservice-in-a-non-activity-class-locationmanager)

Comment: Pretty sure you are dealing with the same thing as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321343/android-getsystemservice-inside-custom-arrayadapter

I found this by searching "ArrayAdapter getSystemService".

Comment: You have to post your log stack to locate where's the error. you can get that by running this command in terminal:> adb logcat *:E

Answer (score 0):

[LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) is a systemService which is used to inflate layouts like the layout for your list item.In order to access any system service,you need some time of context.hence try this.

```
public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserRecord> {
private ArrayList<UserRecord> users;
private Context context

public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<UserRecord>             users) {
super(context, textViewResourceId, users);
this.context=context;
this.users = users;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View v = convertView;
if (v == null) {
//In the following line I get the error: "The method getSystemService is undefined
//for type UserItemAdapter
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
}

UserRecord user = users.get(position);
if (user != null) {
    TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.username);
    TextView email = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.email);

if (username != null) {
    username.setText(user.username);
}

if(email != null) {
    email.setText("Email: " + user.email );
}
}
return v;
}
}
```