# layoutinflater Show NullPonterExecption

Tags: android, android-layout

I can try may code by no result
my app install in device but can`t run
it show error in LayoutInflater

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater l;
    public  ViewPagerAdapter(){

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        l =(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = l.inflate(layouts[position],container,false);
       container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View v= (View)object;
        container.removeView(v);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android getSystemService inside custom ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321343/android-getsystemservice-inside-custom-arrayadapter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please share the full exception and stack trace. Right now my guess is that `layouts` is null or it's something else unrelated to this code.

Answer (score -1):

Use `LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext())` or `container.getContext().getSystemService()` to obtain your `inflater` instance

Comment: `ViewPagerAdapter` looks like an inner class otherwise he wouldn't be able to call `getSystemService` directly. NPE comes probably from somewhere else.

Answer (score -1):

You can access the `system services` through `context` like below code

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

You should pass the context to the `ViewPagerAdapter` through constructor, through which you can access the `systemServices` to get the `inflater`.

Comment: `ViewPagerAdapter` looks like an inner class otherwise he wouldn't be able to call `getSystemService` directly. NPE comes probably from somewhere else.

Answer (score -2):

Initialise your Inflater using,

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater().from(context);
```

Comment: Ctrl + click on `from` and you'll see the method does exactly what OP already does.

Comment: @ Eugen Pechanec, How are you taking value of context ??

Comment: And where does your `context` come from? I'm assuming `ViewPagerAdapter` is an inner class in activity otherwise he wouldn't be able to call `getSystemService` and get a *compile time error* instead of a crash.

Comment: @EugenPechanec, context come from Activity where you have created object of ViewPagerAdapter,

 mAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(this, viewPager)